# Turing machine that calculates word's length

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

The idea of the construction of a composite Turing machine, that (showing to the first symbol of an arbitrary word $w\in \{a,b\}^+$) that writes the length of the word $w$ using the tape letters $0$, $1$ and a blank as a binary number after the word is the following:  (The word can be changed during this calculation.)

The input is deleted step by step, where at each time the binary calculator is increased by $1$. 
For that the recent binary number is read from right to left, until the first zero is found, that is replaced by $1$. 
All previous $1$'s are replaced by $0$'s. 
If the recent binary number consists only by $1$, all the $1$'a except of the leftmost one, are replaced by $0$ and on the right an other $0$ is added.

$$$$

I haven't really understood how it works. When we delete a letter of the word, what do we do to increase the binary calculator by $1$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

In the case at which we want to have the original word at the end of the calculation, one way is the following: the symbols of the word are marked instead of deleted (for example with $a^{\star}$ or $a'$). After the calculation the mark must be deleted.

What exactly does it mean that the TM marks a position? That it overwrites that position?

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to answer your question; it describes how to increment by 1 in binary. For example, if the current number is 10010111, the calculator will find the rightmost 0, replace it by 1, and replace the three 1s to the right of it by 0s: 10011000.

Comment: If we have for example the word $w=abbaabaa$, do we delete the first $a$ and write after a blank the number $1$ , so $\_bbaabaa \_ 1$ ? @Théophile

Comment: And if we delete an ther one we add again a $1$ on the right: $\_ \ \_baabaa \_ 11$ ? Or do we do something else? @Théophile

Comment: After the second deletion we do something else: since our number consists only by $1$'s we are changing to zero all the $1$'s after it (in our case there are none) and adding a zero, so our tape will look like this: $\_\_ baabaa \_ 10$

Comment: So, do we have the following? $$\ldots \_ abbaabaa\_ \ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_bbaabaa\_ 1\ldots \\  \ \ldots \_ \_ baabaa\_ 10\ldots \\ \ \ldots \_ \_ \_ aabaa\_ 11\ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_ \_ \_ abaa\_ 100\ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ baa\_ 101\ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ aa\_ 110\ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_a\_ 111\ldots \\ \ldots \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_\_ \_ 1000\ldots$$  @AsafHaas

Comment: I have also an other question. In the case at which we want to have the original word at the end of the calculation, one way is the following: the symbols of the word are marked instead of deleted (for example with $a^{\star}$ or $a'$). After the calculation the mark must be deleted. What exactly does it mean that the TM marks a position? @AsafHaas

Comment: About your first comment: exactly.

Comment: About your second comment: it means that instead of deleting the input character from the tape (by writing "empty" into the cell), the TM writes in the cell it read a $a^*$ in case it read $a$, and a $a^\prime$ in case it read a $b$. That way it can distinct between what was in the past an $a$, a $b$ or empty in the first place, and at the end of its running it can go back and replace all the markings with the original input.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you so much!! :-) @AsafHaas

Comment: I am looking again this issue. How do we see that the machine of the description in my initial post is a **composite** Turing machine? @AsafHaas

Comment: Also, at is it important if we start to delete the letters from left to right or from right to left? @AsafHaas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly describe the successive contents on the tape in the comments: yes, that's exactly what the machine will do.

Now, as to your second question:  To mark the symbols in the word you do indeed simply use a different symbol, but from which you can recover the original symbol. So, for example, we can replace an 'a' with an 'A', and a 'b' with a 'B'.  As such, the successive contents on the tape will look like this:

$$...abbaabaa...$$

$$...abbaabaA.1.$$

$$...abbaabAa.10.$$

$$...abbaaBaa.11.$$

$$...abbaAbaa.100.$$

$$...abbAabaa.101.$$

$$...abBaabaa.110.$$

$$...aBbaabaa.111.$$

$$...Abbaabaa.1000.$$

$$...abbaabaa.1000.$$

Note that the capital letter will tell the machine which letters it has counted.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You're welcome! :)

Comment: I am looking again this issue. How do we see that the machine of the description in my initial post is a **composite** Turing machine?

Comment: Also, at your example is it important if we start to replace the letters from left to right or from right to left?

Comment: @MaryStar I have always understood the notion of a composite Turing-machine to be a completely informal one: it is one put together from smaller ones. But how do you define smaller ones? One can always consider any machine with two or more nodes to be a composition of smaller ones. So, unless your book uses a more specific and precise definition of a compositie Turing-machine, this is not anything to worry about

Comment: @MaryStar Also, you can go left to right as well as right to left

Comment: Do you mean that a composite Turing machine is a composition of various machines, where each machine has a specific purpose/does a specific task?

Comment: @MaryStar Correct .... but like I said: it's hard to put a mathematical definition to this. So, this notion really just makes the practical point that we can string together a bunch of existing machines.